# Reading data from lego ultrasonic/color sensor via Android app

Tags: android, sensors, lego-mindstorms

I am working on app for Android for controlling Lego Mindstorm. I have done the basics (I can connect, send, recieve messages), so I can control motors. But I have problem with sensors. I have ultrasonic and color sensor connected. To control ultrasonic sensor I send a message SETINPUTMODE with Lowspeed9V and Rawmode parameters, but when I use GETINPUTVALUES it always returns distance 0. I tried using other sensor types in message but it returns 0 or value that doesn't change with real distance . When it comes to the color sensor it doesn't even shine, no matter what parameters I use (sensors are working I checked directly on NXT and via PC). What I need is an advice, whether I am doing something wrong, or a working code that doesn't require installing anything on robot, because it is school property. Thanks

Comment: have a look here: http://hsrc.static.net/Research/NXT%20I2C%20Communication/
I had the same problem.
It is not completly working as I want.
If you have some details by now give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

**1. Set the input mode with the SETINPUTMODE (0x05) command with the parameters LOWSPEED__9V (0x0B) and RAWMODE (0x00).**

So the **SETINPUTMODE** command will send the following bytes **{0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x0B, 0x00}** where:

```
 0x00: DIRECT REPLY or 0x80 DIRECT NO REPLY
 0x05: SETINPUTMODE
 0x03: Port where the sensor is connected. The documentation recommends port 4 for ultrasonic sensor.
 0x0B: LOWSPEED__9V
 0x00: RAWMODE
```

**2. Tell NXT how many bytes you're expecting for the answer with the LSWRITE (0x0F) command.**

So the **LSWRITE** command will send the following bytes **{0x00, 0x0F, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x42}** where:

```
0x00: DIRECT REPLY or 0x80 DIRECT NO REPLY
0x0F: LSWRITE
0x03: Port where the sensor is connected. The documentation recommends port 4 for ultrasonic sensor.
0x02: Tx -> Transmitted Data Length
0x01: Rx -> Receive Data Length
0x02: Byte 5 is the i2c address of the device, for the NXT it is usually 0x02.
0x42: This is the register you are attempting to write to. It is device dependent. For the NXT Ultrasonic Sensor 0x41 is used for commands, and the read registers are in 0x42 to 0x49 so you could use any from 0x42 to 0x49.
```

**3. Tell NXT you're ready to receive the answer with LSGETSTATUS (0x0E) command.**

So the **LSGETSTATUS** command will send the following bytes **{0x00, 0x0e, 0x03}** where:

```
0x00: DIRECT REPLY
0x0E: LSGETSTATUS
0x03: Port where the sensor is connected. The documentation recommends port 4 for ultrasonic sensor.
```

**4. Wait for a reply with a success value = 0x00.**

So once reached this point you must keep sending the **LSGETSTATUS** command until you get that success (0) you've being getting all the time because that means that the answer is ready to be read. If **LSGETSTATUS** reply returns with a value different from 0 then the answer is not ready. Give it some time, maybe 300 milliseconds.

A correct reply data will look like this **{0x02, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x01}** where:

```
0x02: REPLY
0x0E: LSGETSTATUS
0x00: SUCCESS (different from 0x00 means a specific error. Take a look at the documentation if you need to)
0x01: Bytes ready to be read.
```

**5. Read the value with the LSREAD (0x10) command.**

So the **LSREAD** command will send the following bytes **{0x00, 0x10, 0x03}** where:

```
0x00: DIRECT REPLY
0x10: LSREAD
0x03: Port where the sensor is connected. The documentation recommends port 4 for ultrasonic sensor.
```

**6. You will have the distance in centimeters as soon as the NXT brick responds.**

A correct reply data will look like this **{0x02, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, byte1, byte2, byte3, ……, byte19}** where:

```
0x02: REPLY
0x10: LSREAD
0x00: SUCCESS (different from 0x00 means a specific error. Take a look at the documentation if you need to)
0x01: Bytes that contains the answer. You asked for 1 byte.
byte1...byte19: Zero-padded -> HERE IS THE ANSWER
```

Read the first byte for the answer which corresponds to the 5th byte of the array. Its value will be the distance read by the sensor. The range is from 1 to 255 centimeters.

**7. Repeat steps 2 to 6 in a loop to keep asking the sensor for the distance constantly.**